# How to change global variable from inside the class and access in different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class A : UIViewController {

var b = B()
...

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

         print("inside view will appear")
         print(b.transferText) // Here showing Goku only
    }


}
```

And Second class

```
class B : UIViewController{
var transferText = "Goku"
 ...

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.transferText = "vegeta"
    }

}
```

So I have to basically transfer the transferText from class B to A, when i click the **UINavigationBar** Back button. Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: override prepareForSegueMethod and instead of assigning  new  B ref to b, give ref of destinationViewController.

Comment: If you are declared viewController B then it is doesn't exist while popBackController . so using delegate you can pass data B to A .

Comment: How to use prepareFOrSegueMethod with the UIBack button.

Comment: Please update your question if you need to pass data from child to parent(Class B - Class A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using delegation pattern would be a nice solution for passing data from child to parent (In your case - Class B to Class A) as you're saying Class A Has Class B instance and need to post data back to the parent when an event occurs.

1) Declare a protocol in Class B.

```
import UIKit
protocol ClassBDelegate
{
    func didUpdate(strTransferText : String)
}    
class B: UIViewController
{
    // Should have valid connection from your Interface builder to this function.
    @IBAction func navBarBtnUpdateClickked(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        // on Navigation bar click,Update transferText and fire the delegate again.
        transferText = "Updated Goku by navigation bar button tap"
        didTapNavigationbarButton();
    }
    var transferText = "Goku" // Default.
    var delegate : ClassBDelegate? // Declare a public variable to store delegate.
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Update transferText and fire delegate.
        transferText = "Updated Goku by navigation bar button tap"
        didTapNavigationbarButton(); // fire delegate from ViewWill appear.
    }
    private func didTapNavigationbarButton() -> Void
    {
        // Need to notify Instance of A class from here.
        // Using Delegation pattern!
        if(delegate != nil)
        {
            delegate!.didUpdate(strTransferText: transferText);
        }
     }
```

}

2) Confirm to ClassBDelegate in Class A and implement the delegate.

```
// Confirming to ClassB Delegate
class A: UIViewController,ClassBDelegate 
{
    var b : B?
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup a segue in storyboard to move from class A to Class B to get class B Instance.
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        b = segue.destination as? B
        b?.delegate = self
        print("inside Prepare for segue function of Class A")
        print(b?.transferText) // Here showing Goku only(Default value).
    }
    internal func didUpdate(strTransferText: String)
    {
        print("Updated transferText in Class B " + strTransferText);
    }
}
```

3) There you go,You'll get call backs for Class A instance whenever button pressed in Class B.

- you can achieve it by other ways like Observer pattern(NSNotificationCenter) or KVO pattern and even with Singleton pattern(Not applicable always).

Hope this helps to explore the best fit for your requirement.

Happy to help :)

Comment: Well..I didn't knew about delegates. Thanks for very detailed answer.

Comment: Anytime,Happy to help:)

Comment: Great explanation about the delegation pattern,Thanks.

Comment: @NareshReddyM How to have valid connection from Interface builder to this function ? to the back button.

Comment: Drop a UIBarButton in-place of back button on to the navigation bar and connect it to the above function.

Comment: @NareshReddyM Thanks that worked. Can you tell me how to get values in settingsViewController to the FirstViewController immediately upon opening the app ?

Comment: I can't tell you with the info what you provided,Could you be more specific on settings view controller and first view controller?

Answer (score 3):

Use static variable to do that

```
class B : UIViewController{
static var transferText = "Goku"
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        B.transferText = "vegeta"
    }

}
```

in A class Use

```
print(B.transferText)
```

or for use after navigation back you can use completion handler , when navigation back just call that completion block with text.

Comment: Just what i needed !!

Answer (score 0):

In class B, you declare property for A class

```
var a = A()
```

And in the B's viewWillDisappear, put

```
a.transferText = "vegeta"
```

(you declared property transferText in A class).